# Template suggestions for page on specific node id

Tags: 7, theming

I created 2 nodes of the content type page for which i want to create a custom template file.
In the theme_hook_suggestions array there is an element with 'node__821' so i created the file node--821.tpl.php but it doesn't work.

I also tried page--node--821.tpl.php, this works in that it uses the file but this replaces the page.tpl.php and thats not what i need.

According to http://drupal.org/node/1089656 my filenames should work, but since they don't anyone an idea why? Could it have something to do with the page content type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things before this will work:

- Make sure you have a copy of the original node.tpl.php file in your theme folder (the overridden template file will not be picked up otherwise).
- Clear Drupal's cache

Other than that everything you're doing is perfect so that should fix the problem.